# Why would binding the callback be preferred over using thisArg in JavaScript Array methods?

Tags: javascript

Douglas Crockford mentions in his video series "The Douglas Crockford JavaScript Master Class" that the `thisArg` found in JavaScript Array methods, such as `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])` is a mistake in the language, and binding the passed callback using `callback.bind(thisArg)` is better.

Why would that be preferable?

Comment: It isn't a mistake, and can be very useful. Using `.bind()` creates a new function object. Seems wasteful when not needed.

Comment: Did Crockford bother to give a reason?

Comment: If I recall, Crockford also called HTML5 a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `bind()` is a consistent pattern, but seeing arguments tacked on the end of things often require documentation lookup if you're not familiar with the argument signature.

I think it's useful, but I can see his position too. Crockford has a lot to say about JavaScript, but it's only ever one person's opinion.